# BackgroundWorker example

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Could you please provide an example how to use background worker.
I have created Background worker follow the instruction provided in documentation for asp.net boilerplate. Inherit my class from

```
public class ContactValidationBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorkerBase, ITransientDependency
```

Override Start method and put into non-blocking Task.Run(MyMethod). Then I add wait instruction into Overrided method WaitToStop, add like myTask.Wait();

This method starts , but it block performing main process of work. 
I'm using Asp.net(boilerplate) core + Angular (SPA) 
I added it into Application Services layer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //defining the backgroundworker
    private BackgroundWorker bgworker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initializeBackgroundWorker();
    }

    private void initializeBackgroundWorker()
    {
        bgworker.DoWork += MyBackgroundWorker_DoWork;
    }

    private void MyBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //method you want to execute in the backgroundWorker
        MyMethod();
    }

    private void Mouse_Enter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //call the backgroundWorker and execute it
        //This will execute the method simultaneouly with other methods 
        //without blocking the UI 

        bgworker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void MyMethod()
    {
        //your method's code
    }

}
```

The above code shows how to `define, initialize and execute` a `backgroundWorker` in a WPF or winform application using C#.
Refer to the inline comments in the code to understand what each part of code does.

Comment: No. I need example for background worker accordantly to aspnetvoilerplate and net core 2. That is not suite as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MakeInactiveUsersPassiveWorker : PeriodicBackgroundWorkerBase, ISingletonDependency
{
    private readonly IRepository<User, long> _userRepository;

    public MakeInactiveUsersPassiveWorker(AbpTimer timer, IRepository<User, long> userRepository)
        : base(timer)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        Timer.Period = 5000; //5 seconds (good for tests, but normally will be more)
    }

    [UnitOfWork]
    protected override void DoWork()
    {
        using (CurrentUnitOfWork.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant))
        {
            var oneMonthAgo = Clock.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(30));

            var inactiveUsers = _userRepository.GetAllList(u =>
                u.IsActive &&
                ((u.LastLoginTime < oneMonthAgo && u.LastLoginTime != null) || (u.CreationTime < oneMonthAgo && u.LastLoginTime == null))
                );

            foreach (var inactiveUser in inactiveUsers)
            {
                inactiveUser.IsActive = false;
                Logger.Info(inactiveUser + " made passive since he/she did not login in last 30 days.");
            }

            CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Read => https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Background-Jobs-And-Workers